# Shared Elements appearing over Actionbar

Tags: android, android-actionbar

I am having a hard time with shared elements overlapping the different built in ui elements in android. I have found answers for the navbar and the status bar, but the action bar eludes me.

In the code, you can see where I have "test". That value is what i am searching for (i tested "test" for status bar and nav bar to see the effects)

The issue I am having, is with back pressed. The overlaps occurs. The initial animation into the new activity works just fine.

```
           Pair<View, String> pair = Pair.create(navigationBar, Window.NAVIGATION_BAR_BACKGROUND_TRANSITION_NAME);
            Pair<View, String> pair1 = Pair.create((View) holder.thumbnail, "thumbnail");
            Pair<View, String> pair2 = Pair.create(statusBar, Window.STATUS_BAR_BACKGROUND_TRANSITION_NAME);
            Pair<View, String> pair3 = Pair.create(actionBar, "test");
```